# pyspark change day in datetime column

Tags: python, date, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

what is wrong with this code trying to change day of a datetime columns

```
import pyspark
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf
import pyspark.sql.types as sparktypes
import datetime

sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="test")
sqlcontext = pyspark.SQLContext(sc)

rdd = sc.parallelize([('a',datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 9, 0, 0)),
                      ('b',datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 27, 0, 0)),
                      ('c',datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 31, 0, 0))])
testdf = sqlcontext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["id", "date"])

print(testdf.show())
print(testdf.printSchema())
```

gives a test dataframe:

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|                date|
+---+--------------------+
|  a|2014-01-09 00:00:...|
|  b|2014-01-27 00:00:...|
|  c|2014-01-31 00:00:...|
+---+--------------------+


root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Then I define a udf to change day of date column:

```
def change_day_(date, day):
    return date.replace(day=day)

change_day = sf.udf(change_day_, sparktypes.TimestampType())
testdf.withColumn("PaidMonth", change_day(testdf.date, 1)).show(1)
```

This raises an error:

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method col([class java.lang.Integer]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:339)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Perhaps try replacing `1` (in call to `change_day`) with `lit(1)`, after doing `from pyspark.sql.functions import lit`?

Comment: Thanks! That worked!!

Comment: @ArthurTacca could you please explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A udf which recieves multiple arguments is assumed to recieve multiple **columns**. The "1" is not a column.

This means you can do one of the following. Either make it a column as suggested in the comments:

```
testdf.withColumn("PaidMonth", change_day(testdf.date, lit(1))).show(1)
```

lit(1) is a column of ones

or make the original function return a higher order function:

```
def change_day_(day):
    return lambda date: date.replace(day=day)

change_day = sf.udf(change_day_(1), sparktypes.TimestampType())
testdf.withColumn("PaidMonth", change_day(testdf.date)).show(1)
```

This basically creates a function which replaces with 1 and therefore can recieve an integer. The udf would apply on a single column.

Comment: your second solution works but i don't understand how the date argument is passed

Comment: the cahnge_day_ function creates a function. This function uses the day parameter from change_day_ as a constant.

Comment: @muon To put it another way, with `lit(1)` the number one is passed as a parameter to `change_day` *on the workers*. With this solution, `change_day_()` is passed the number 1 *on the driver*, which returns a function that is then passed to the workers. (The second function contains a hidden copy of the number 1, so the number 1 is still ultimately passed to all the workers.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ArthurTacca's comment, the trick is to use `pyspark.sql.functions.lit()` function like this:

```
testdf.withColumn("PaidMonth", change_day(testdf.date, sf.lit(1))).show()
```

alternate answers welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but in case someone else comes across this.
If you prefer built-in functions you can use [date_trunc()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_trunc.html) along with [date_add()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_add.html) "to change day of a datetime columns".

```py
# change to 1 as in the original question
testdf.withColumn("PaidMonth", f.date_trunc("mon", col("date")))
# change to another day eg. 6
testdf.withColumn("PaidMonth", f.date_add(f.date_trunc("mon", col("date")), 5))
```

Also useful for date manipulations are [last_day()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.last_day.html) and [date_sub()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_sub.html)