# Spark (scala) change date in datetime column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

[pyspark change day in datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583433/pyspark-change-day-in-datetime-column)

I'm trying to do something similar to the answer above. I'm getting 
`value replace is not a member of java.sql.Timestamp`

```
val changeDay = udf((date:java.sql.Timestamp) => {
  val day = 1
  date.replace(day=day)
})
val df2 = df1.withColumn("newDateTime", changeDay($"datetime"))
```

What I can't figure out is what functions are available for this `java.sql.Timestamp` object. When I google it, it almost seems like the answers are not related to the same type.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `Timestamp` to `java.time`'s [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) and change its `day` value via `withDayOfMonth(day)`, as shown below:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1, Timestamp.valueOf("2019-03-07 12:30:00")),
  (2, Timestamp.valueOf("2019-04-08 09:00:00"))
).toDF("id", "ts")

def changeDay(day: Int) = udf{ (ts: Timestamp) =>
  import java.time.LocalDateTime
  val changedTS = ts.toLocalDateTime.withDayOfMonth(day)
  Timestamp.valueOf(changedTS)
}

df.withColumn("newTS", changeDay(1)($"ts")).show
// +---+-------------------+-------------------+
// | id|                 ts|              newTS|
// +---+-------------------+-------------------+
// |  1|2019-03-07 12:30:00|2019-03-01 12:30:00|
// |  2|2019-04-08 09:00:00|2019-04-01 09:00:00|
// +---+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

so this probably isn't the best way to do this but here is one way

```
val DateTimeString = date.toString()
val DTtime = DateTimeString.split(" ")(1)
DTday + " " + DTtime
```